# Plot of complicated expression takes very long time

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I have some long expressions that I got from multiplication and addition of matrices and vectors of order 4:

```
P0 = Transpose[Eigenvectors[leadinMatrix0 /. rullistFull]];
dia0 = DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[leadinMatrix0 /. rullistFull]];
Z0t0 = Inverse[P0].{0, 0, 1, 0};
eigenCons0 = Inverse[dia0].Inverse[P0].consVector0 ;
Z0 = MatrixExp[dia0*t].Z0t0 + MatrixExp[dia0*t].eigenCons0 - eigenCons0; 
analSol = P0.Z0;
```

Where "P0" and "dia0" depends on one variable and contain Root objects.
Now, when I'm trying to plot the elements of the vector "analSol" as a function of the variable for certain "t"  it takes hours, and sometimes even a day.

Is there a way to make the ploting much faster (seconds or minutes)?

Comment: Try turning all of these definitions into delayed functions of `t`, like `P0[t_?NumericQ] := ...` and `analSol[t_?NumericQ] := P0[t].Z0[t]` etc. In this way the inversion, eigenvalues, etc. will be done numerically for each value of `t` instead of analytically once and for all. It's difficult to give more concrete advice without working code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give a suggestion without being able to try it out, as there's no complete code in the original post:

```
analSol[t_?NumericQ] := Module[{diag,P0,P0inv,Z0t0,eigenCons0,Z0},
  diag = Eigensystem[leadinMatrix0[t] /. rullistFull[t]];
  P0 = Transpose[diag[[2]]];
  P0inv = Inverse[P0];
  Z0t0 = P0inv.{0, 0, 1, 0};
  eigenCons0 = (P0inv.consVector0[t])/diag[[1]];
  Z0 = Exp[diag[[1]]*t]*(Z0t0 + eigenCons0) - eigenCons0; 
  P0.Z0]
```

The main changes are:

- delayed function that only works with numerical values for `t`
- eigenvalues and eigenvectors are calculated together, using `Eigensystem`
- multiplication by diagonal matrices are replaced by element-wise multiplications or divisions by the diagonal elements
- matrix-exponentiation of diagonal matrices is replaced by exponentiation of the diagonal elements

A further speedup could come from the eigenvectors: if your matrix `leadinMatrix0` has certain properties, then the inverse of `P0` may be equal to the transpose of `P0`; try it out! This would speed up `P0inv` greatly.

If you give complete code that we can run and play with, I'll be able to debug this.

Comment: It works perfect! Thank's a lot.